# Tips for managing security in my applications

Tags: c#, android, angular, encryption, pgp

I have an ApiRest, the database in MySql and two clients, one is web in angular6 and the other is an Android application.

I want to know what security measures, I must take to keep the information secure in request and response, maybe use pgp or aes or something else and where.

At that moment, I use Https, and for the login, I send the password and the user in plain text in the body of a POST method, to obtain a token, and in the server I do the hashing of this password with a salt, and I save it in the database.

thanks for your help

Comment: What part of your application is this relevant to?  What you're doing at the moment is pretty standard.

Comment: I want protect the request from clients to server and I want to know if i need a specific thing in database

Comment: HTTPS protects network traffic between your client and server - this part is fine.  The main thing is to ensure you aren't hashing your password with an algorithm that isn't designed for password hashing.  If you're using MD5, SHA etc. then this is a problem.  You should be using argon2, bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2.